# Android SearchView wont work when loading fragments

Tags: android, searchview

I am creating an application that is composed of one activity and few fragments, in my activity I added a **SearchView** hoping for it to be available all the time like in **googleplay**.

In the code below SearchView fails to work whenever I add  **loadFragment(new FragmentSearch());** in the oncreate method.

I need **loadFragment(new FragmentSearch());** to load my fragment upon creation of the application.

Please provide solution as well as enlighten me of why this error happens.

```
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
    BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
Toolbar toolbar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
    toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    BottomNavigationView navigation = findViewById(R.id.navigation);
    navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    loadFragment(new FragmentSearch());//this code causes error

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.search_menu,menu);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
    return true;
}

public boolean loadFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    if (fragment != null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.frameContainer, fragment)
                .commit();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    Fragment fragment = null;
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.navigation_search:
            fragment = new FragmentSearch();
            break;
        case R.id.navigation_graph:
            fragment = new FragmentGraph();
            break;
    }
    return loadFragment(fragment);
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {

    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {

    return false;
}
}
```

Here is the fragment. I think the error is in the fragment code, though I can't find it.

```
public class FragmentSearch extends Fragment {
private static final String TAG = "FragmentSearch";
RecyclerView productsRecyclerView;
RecyclerViewAdapter adapter;
RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
ArrayList<Product> productArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreateView: ");
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search, null);
    productsRecyclerView = v.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview_search);
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
    productsRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    productsRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    TESTinitializeValueForRecyclerview();
    adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(productArrayList);
    productsRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    return v;
}

private void TESTinitializeValueForRecyclerview() {
    String date = "date";
    String name = "name";
    int sellingPrice = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
        productArrayList.add(new Product(date + i, name + i, sellingPrice + i));


}
 }
```

activity_home.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".HomeActivity">

<include layout="@layout/toolbar_layout" />

<FrameLayout
    android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:id="@+id/frameContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >

</FrameLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
    app:menu="@menu/navigation">


</android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView>

<com.leinardi.android.speeddial.SpeedDialView
    android:id="@+id/speedDial"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_marginBottom="72dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />
```

Comment: Can you post the error? Also include the fragment code.

Comment: **In the code below SearchView fails to work** what do you mean by that?

Comment: Hi, There are no errors I think I need to rephrase that, also I tried to load a different fragment and the searchview worked. Ill add the fragment @Ezzy

Comment: SearchView Wont inflate @BrijeshJoshi

Comment: please share your `activity_home`.

Comment: @BrijeshJoshi and Ezzy I had fix it thank you for your time, as it appears the error was coming from the FrameLayout I just added a paddingTop and somehow it works, note that before adding the paddingTop the Toolbar was visible. Anyway I added the xml file for other people who will be having the same issue.

Comment: @Code-Me Great. Please mark this question as closed. So no one else will try to find solution